# How to use Selenium WebDriver to find Firefox add-ons warning dialog

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I am testing downloading and installing an add-on that our company makes. I can add the domain to the Firefox profile whitelist to eliminate the first dialog, but then FF displays a second one that says "Install add-ons only from authors whom you trust". I can't find a way for Selenium to find it. It's the one that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` - this is not an alert.

I have tried `driver.switchTo().findElement(linkText("Install")` - nothing found.

I have tried using [SikuliWebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver) to find an element by location (picking some random ints to work off of) and then just send keys like `Keys.TAB` and `Keys.ENTER`, but as I step through in debug mode, `driver.findELementByLocation(20,40)` never returns.

I have tried `driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.TAB)` (sending two tabs and an enter). Also never returns.

I think this dialog is generated by Javascript but I am unable to find out what JS generates it. Ideally I could find a name or an id for the button in the dialog and then use `JavascriptExecutor` to run the command. But without any kind of handle I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) reports this dialog is from `chrome://mozapps/content/xpinstall/xpinstallConfirm.xul` and has an ID of `xpinstallConfirm`. The button is initially disabled with `label="Install (3)"`. The button is enabled 3 seconds after the dialog gains focus (the number in the label counts down). The text label for the enabled button is `Install Now`. However, if the dialog looses focus that button becomes disabled again and an additional 3 second wait is required after focus is regained. Are you waiting the 3 seconds?

Comment: I can't repro your findings. When I try to view the dialog info in the DOM Inspector browser, it shows me nothing.

Comment: however, i did find xpinstallConfirm.xul online and that id `xpinstallConfirm` is for the overall dialog. Selenium cannot find the element by id, it just hangs. Is Selenium incapable of getting at this dialog box at all, does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can only see the DOM (document object model). It can't test desktop applications. The dialog shown is part of the Firefox application and not part of the DOM, so Selenium can't see or access or interact with it. Sad but true. Try Ranorex?